# Embedded Service - Offline Chat Deployment in Communities

Tags: community, chat, embedded-services, offline

I'm trying to customize my embedded service offline service, instead of showing the form to create an offline case, I want to change it to a text and a button to redirect.

So far (before using communities) we handed the snippet to the client and it worked well, but now using communities I can't change it to the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually got a workaround to this issue.

When using communities if you had a default Embedded Service chat into the page, in the left section (options) you'll have an input for a static resource called 'Snippet Settings File'.

First things first, you need to create a JS to be uploaded into Salesforce as a static resource (set it to public)

Here's a snippet of what I've made (there are probably more accessible ways of achieving this)

```
var parentChat;
var redirectButton;

embedded_svc.addEventHandler("afterMaximize", function(data) {
    waitForElement('[data-aura-class="uiButton--default uiButton embeddedServiceSidebarButton"]').then(result => {
        var btn = result;
        var btnSpan = btn.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        if (btnSpan.innerHTML == 'btn_value') {
            createRedirection();
            var d = document.querySelectorAll('[data-aura-class="embeddedServiceSidebarForm"]')[0];
            d.replaceWith(parentChat);
            btn.replaceWith(redirectButton);
        }
    });
});

function createRedirection() {
    var urlOrigin = 'https://www.google.com';
    parentChat = document.createElement('liveAgent:clientChat');
    var chatAlertMessage = document.createElement(
        'liveAgent:clientChatAlertMessage'
    );
    var infoTable = document.createElement('table');
    infoTable.setAttribute('id', 'waitingMessage');
    infoTable.setAttribute('cellpadding', '0');
    infoTable.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
    infoTable.setAttribute('style', 'margin-top: 150px;');
    var infoTableTr = document.createElement('tr');
    var infoTableTd = document.createElement('td');
    infoTableTd.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: center');
    var infoTableData = document.createTextNode(
        'Chat Content'
    );
    redirectButton = document.createElement('button');
    redirectButton.setAttribute("onclick", "location.href='" + urlOrigin + "';");
    redirectButton.setAttribute("class", "submitButton uiButton--default uiButton embeddedServiceSidebarButton offlinebutton");
    redirectButton.setAttribute("id", "contactformbutton");
    redirectButton.setAttribute("style", "display: block");
    redirectButton.setAttribute("data-aura-unique", "true-unique");
    redirectButton.innerHTML = 'Redirect to new Page';

    infoTableTd.appendChild(infoTableData);
    infoTableTr.appendChild(infoTableTd);
    infoTable.appendChild(infoTableTr);
    parentChat.appendChild(chatAlertMessage);
    parentChat.appendChild(infoTable);
}

async function waitForElement(selector, timeout = 20000) {
    const start = Date.now();

    while (Date.now() - start < timeout) {
        const el = document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0];
        if (el) {
            return el;
        }
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 250));
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the line 'if (btnSpan.innerHTML == 'btn_value') {' change the btn_value for the current value shown when the Widget Contact form is shown

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option to replace offline form with custom component. we dont have such option under embedded service dpeloyment settings. We can customize the prechat form but not offline support form.